# Ideas on how to implement the color wheel, and find the related information using RGB in computer?

Tags: image, image-processing, colors

[image]

Here is a color wheel, typically from the web. I would like to create something like the user input the `Yellow` color code, and I am able to find the complementary color of `Yellow` is purple. Also, I would like to find the nearby color, `light green`, and the `light orange`. How can I implement it in a computer science way? or any existing algorithm to do so? Thanks.

Comment: Four seconds with google yielded [How to Calculate a Complementary Colour](http://serennu.com/colour/rgbtohsl.php)

Comment: It should be straightforward in HSV space. Use the same S,V, add +180 degrees to H

Comment: OpenCV would make this really easy for you.  It can convert to HSV for you with cvtColor

Comment: The answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095849/calculating-the-analogous-color-with-python/14116553#14116553 can be directly adjusted for this.