# How to "rotate" the hue of a color?

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uicolor

I want to generate colors that go well with a given `UIColor` (Triadic, Analogues, Complement etc).

I have read a lot of posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095849/calculating-the-analogous-color-with-python/14116553#14116553) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180/function-for-creating-color-wheels) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235072/math-behind-the-colour-wheel). In the last post, The answerer suggested going to easyrgb.com. 
So I went there. I learnt that I need to "rotate" the hue by some degrees if I want to generate those color schemes. For example, for Triadic colors, I need to rotate it by ± 120 degrees.

I know that I can get a color's hue by calling `getHue(:saturation:brightness:)`, but how can I "rotate" it? Isn't the hue returned by the method a number? A number between 0 and 1? This makes no sense to me!

I think the first post might have the answer but the code is written in python. I only learnt a little bit of python so I don't quite know what this means:

```
h = [(h+d) % 1 for d in (-d, d)]           # Rotation by d
```

From the comment, I see that this line somehow rotates the hue by d degrees. But I don't know what that syntax means.

Can anyone tell me how to rotate the hue, or translate the above code to swift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hue component ranges from 0.0 to 1.0, which corresponds to the angle from 0º to 360º in a color wheel (compare [Wikipedia: HSL and HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)).

To "rotate" the hue component by `n` degrees, use:

```
let n = 120 // 120 degrees as an example
hue = fmod(hue + CGFloat(n)/360.0, 1.0)
```

The `fmod()` function is used to normalize the result of
the addition to the range 0.0 to 1.0.

The hue for the complementary color would be

```
let hueComplement = fmod(hue + 0.5, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> **In SwiftUI you can do by using apple documentation code**

```
struct HueRotation: View {
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        ForEach(0..<6) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.linearGradient(
                    colors: [.blue, .red, .green],
                    startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                .hueRotation((.degrees(Double($0 * 36))))
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

}